# How to connect GPS module to usb cable

Tags: usb, serial, wire, gps

I need help with connecting [this module](http://www.ebay.com/itm/NEW-NMEA-Sirf-III-GPS-NAVIGATION-NAVIGATOR-Module-2525-/150750050160?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item2319673770#ht_7779wt_1037) with USB cable or serial cable. What do I need to connect? What channels?

EDIT:

Okay guys I see that you think that this gps in not so good. How about this one? I just need a gps module to connect it to my pc. I have tried searching a gps module with usb but I have found nothing because with usb port we are not talking about module anymore only about gps unit which I don't need.

What about this [gps module](http://www.futurlec.com/EM-410.shtml) and this [cable](http://www.ioiusb.com/Cable/USB-JST.htm)?

I really just want to make gps for vehicle tracking. So I need module and I will make car-pc. Don't worry about program. I am programmer so that's not problem. But connecting all those ports get me confused.

Comment: At a minimum you should give us a link to the datasheet.

Comment: First of all.. Why do you think you can jsut connect a usb cable to it? It does not say USB anywhere on the specs.. it has 2UART ports, hinting that you need to communicate to it via Serial Interface. These channels you talk about, are the amount of locks the GPS moudle can get at once, to increase the accuracy and response time.If you use this for walking, OK. If its going into a fast RC plane, forget about it - Your gps data will be messed up. Good luck

Comment: I have updated my question guys

Comment: Since you are wanting a module just to connect to your computer, there is no electronic design work going on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See table 4.1 on the page you referenced.

It outputs standard NMEA strings asynchronous.
 Std NMEA output is at 4800 bps but this seems to work at 9600 bps according to text in red just after section 6.4.

UARTS are on pins 5,4 and 6,7 TX/RX.

You can probably interface it to USB using a USB to RS232 serial converter. Levels MAY be std RS232 but more likely are 0/+5V. If so you will need a data level translator (such as eg MAX232 or similar).

Comment: The key parameters table speaks about NMEA 0183 std 4800 bps however.

Comment: guys, the baud rate is the least of his problems, he can determine the correct baud rate experimentally as the GPS just spews out sentences and they will either be ascii-decipherable or not

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like an Arduino as a proxy for the module to your PC - but you'd basically just be using it to do the serial UART to USB conversion. The datasheet reads to me that the module has two UART ports, which typically means 0 - 5V levels, but the datasheet is starkly lacking in electrical characterization of the module.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a cheap GPS with a USB interface how about the one Microsoft packages with [Streets and Trips](http://www.amazon.com/s/?ie=UTF8&keywords=streets%20trips%20with%20gps)?